# Libreria de Javascript para modificar archivos de Excel de tipo XLSM

Tags: javascript, excel, libreria, xls

Tengo el siguiente archivo excel, el cual se puede ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de modificar con la librería de javascript, llamada XLSX o SheetJS, pero tengo un problema cuando se genera, ya que solo se genera el texto y en la posición de la celda en que están los valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces yo lo que quiero es conservar todo, los estilos, los colores y los botones del formulario que existen en el archivo.

Con al libreria XLSX, ¿como puedo conservar los estilos de colores de las celdas y los botones con su macro?.

Comment: "Existe alguna librería..." Te recomiendo quitar esa parte, ya que no damos recomendaciones de recursos externos y tu pregunta podría quedar cerrada. Se me ocurre que podés replantear la duda para que veamos como ayudarte con una de las librerías que estás usando, sin pedir recomendaciones de recursos externos.